# Delete My Account

Tags: support, deletion, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I would appreciate if my account could be deleted.  From other meta posts it seems that a moderator needs to do it. Thanks.  I really see no reason whatsoever for not being able to do this ourselves just to put that out there.

Comment: Deleting your account is your own business, obviously, and you are certainly not obligated to explain why.  However, I am slightly curious why people leave Math.SE...  If you feel comfortable doing so, do you think you could give me some insight into the mind of someone who doesn't want their account any more?

Comment: The proper way to request user deletion is by following [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion).

Comment: *Note*: deleting your account does not delete your questions.

Comment: Gah, there go 10 hard-earned reputation points.

Answer (score 15):

As noted in the comments, you can find instructions for deleting your account here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion

Note that unlike *some* sites, we actually do hard-delete your account here - all of your posts are anonymized (they'll be attributed to "user*nnnn*"), your votes on others' posts nullified, your bio, preferences and such erased. If you ever change your mind, there's no guarantee you'll be able to get any of it back. So, y'know, we do try to make sure that's what you really *want* first. Some folks actually don't.

If you do, just follow [the instructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion) and you'll find it removed fairly quickly.

Comment: Damn, he didn't even accept this before getting himself deleted... :D

Comment: @J.M. If he did, the Community bot would have its 33rd accept on meta; it [has 32 so far](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts). And almost 1000 on main site...