# How can I quit this site?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I have had enough of this site so I want to quit by blocking/deleting this account... can someone help me? I guess that I should provide a few legitimate reasons why I want to do this.

1. There has been a lot of instances where I have posted an interesting question (some of which are not answered till date) but it's not upvoted.
2. When I was totally new as a user I found myself helpless by the comments and downvotes of relatively senior guys and also in a few cases when they haven’t been able to answer my question they have typed a number of times: so what does your question mean or so what is your question, although it is perfectly clear to understand.
3. Also there have been instances in the previous case where they have gone to the extent to gang up and close my question.
4. I am very new to MathJax codes but although I typed the question so that there was no problem in reading and understanding the mathematical idea behind it, someone (I don’t want to name) edited it and commented (and I quote) **“ Where on earth do you get your ideas of how to write MathJax code?”**.  I find this particular person among a few others to be extremely keen to edit questions where those changes are not at all necessary and comment in such a manner. I had to mention his name and literally beg his pardon : **“I am a new-learner on MathJax codes, so please pardon my mistakes.”**
5. When I edited some question for betterment someone commented : **“I could answer your edited question but then perhaps you would change it again and we would go on forever.”** , is this the real attitude of this site – since you have edited your question, I know the answer of your question but I won’t let you know!!!
6. Although it is vivid from the previous statements but I’ll still mention it in a different point : **I have found some people (OBVIOUSLY NOT EVERYBODY) very aggressive and rude**, *at the end of the day I am here to learn Mathematics not to indulge in any sort of quarreling.*

So if anyone knows how to ***block / delete my account and also delete all my activities till date***, then please let me know.

Comment: [Contact us](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) and use the "I need to delete my user profile" option. But anything you have contributed to Mathematics Stack Exchange has been licensed to Stack Exchange in perpetuity (see [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal)).

Comment: See also: [Delete My Account](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9456).

Comment: Looking at your 18 not deleted questions (I can't access deleted posts yet)  people were either helpful or neutral except the 4th point you mentioned (the last question). Also notice that you can flag comments for being rude and if you think your question was closed unjustly you can post it here on meta (there is a post called something like reopen, undeletion requests). Anyway if you still wish to leave this site farewell and best regards.

Comment: Lmao with the MathJax, I do think most people are understanding of such errors.

Comment: Sometimes when I ask seemingly interesting questions that get about 5 views within the first hour (-_-) I try asking/advertising a bit in the [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), people there sure know lots of things.  And you don't need upvotes on your questions for it to be interesting.

Comment: "Also there have been instances in the previous case where they have gone to the extent to gang up and close my question." - I don't think people gang up to close your questions, rather, questions that are in the process of being closed will often be sent to the review queue, where people then decide if the question is worthy of being closed or not.  Generally, I recommend referring [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?s=1|2.3832) when deciding if your questions are up to site standards.

Comment: For the 5th point, just be sure your answers don't change the question to the extent that it invalidates previous answers.  Note that your questions aren't meant just for you, as other people will eventually see them as well, perhaps due to having the same question as you did.  IMHO, editing questions so that some answers become useless really destroys the point of the site, which would be to create a network of questions and corresponding answers that can be referred to and learned from, not just personal learning, but for everyone.

Comment: I think the ganging up comment is very apt - it is precisely the behaviour I have observed by existing users to new users. What is worse is that the existing users who do this down-voting or voting to CLOSE sometimes have no experience or knowledge in the subject area, and may be closing off perfectly reasonable questions, in circumstances where they likely know less about the subject area than the OP. That is ultimately a reflection of the breadth of the mathSE site, and the demands made on all users to try and help out.

Comment: Try to think it one more time, I would not like that you to leave this site. Courage and good luck.

Comment: @wolfies  I think I've recently encountered just this rant of yours very very recently.

Comment: Phil Jones:  If you are concerned about an issue or two, that's what meta is for.  If you came here to make public your declaration of deletion-hood, this isn't to place to say that.  If  you want to leave the site, you've now been given instructions on how to do so, and "reasons" for doing so are not required.  You've got the guidelines to delete your account.  No need to make your exit so dramatic.

Comment: Phil Jones:  I also understand the when one feels attacked, it is certainly understandable to retreat.  The user you speak of is not highly regarded;  and I'm sorry if I sounded a bit "cold" to you, in my comment above.  Please sit on it... wait... before seeking to have your account deleted.  It seems that you are doing that, and I'm very happy you haven't acted on deleting your account.

Comment: .....To be honest, there have been a handful of times where I felt I needed to leave the site, and three of those times I used "contact us" in order to have my account deleted.  But I never was certain enough to write "delete me" in my profile.  In the end, I knew I really didn't want to leave the site, but was rather reacting to the poor conduct of others.  Hold your head high, and don't let the user that attacked you have to power to decide your departure.

Answer (score 6):

To delete you account, go to the [relevant help-center page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) and follow the instructions. In your case this amounts to follow the "contact us" link (as explained in a comment). Check whether you receive an email response and follow the instructions there. Then there may be a small wait, but eventually you account will be gone. (It may also happen more directly as your account is relatively new.)

However, as explained on that link your content will not be deleted. It will be made anonymous though.

Please do not try to delete your content manually before leaving; this would be undone and thus it would just waste your time and that of the person that has to undo it.

On the general situation, many users here are rather direct and cut it short. 
Reasons for this include, personal style, culture, and last but not least efficiency, when they do the same thing over and over again. While this may seems rude, the intent is most of the time not to be rude.

Incidentally, the user you would not name has themselves repeatedly expressed concern about poor treatment of (new) users. I am sure their intent was to be helpful, and the sentence you quote expressed an honest surprise and curiosity how you could get the idea to write in this form. To look at it in a positive way, this feedback (even if not expressed in the most polite form) can help you to improve your skills.

Comment: `On the general situation, many users here are rather direct and cut it short. Reasons for this include, personal style, culture, and last but not least efficiency, when they do the same thing over and over again`   ...........In effect, what you are saying is that mathSE has grown too large and too cumbersome, attracts too many posts, is under-resourced to deal with them, and allows people who are skilled in area A (but not B) to moderate  content on B, leading to unsatisfactory outcomes.

Comment: I would not say that it is *too* large  in an absolute sense (SO is about an order of magnitude larger and still functions). But, yes, the site has grown quite large, has a rapid turnover, and this does influence the style of the site (towards the direct and short). I find the last part astonishing given the current situation. A main concern for them were issues with their use of MathJax, or rather the lack of it. The editor(s) seemed competent in making their corrections; OP did not like the way they approached it or the fact that corrections were made at all.

Comment: Furthermore, from what I can see, I do not feel that OP had that poor a reception on the site. But maybe I looked at the wrong places. Part of the problem might be that some users have unreasonable expectations on what level of "service" one can expect on a  free site mostly run by volunteers. Sure, the site should be welcoming, but I feel it is not untowardly to expect that users try to make a good faith effort to get familiar with and then to comply with the customs of the site. Finally,it's not always necessary to understand the math in detail to be able to see that a question is lacking.

Comment: All worthy sentiments which I completely agree with. But then, at the same time, there is a complaint from a person so unhappy with their treatment that they wish to cancel their entire account (such is their level of discontent), the same downvoting of the complaint ('see no evil, hear no evil'), and an apparent unwillingness to seek ways to accommodate those concerns. This person is not the first to raise these concerns - nor will they be the last.

Comment: You did not reply to my question if you bothered to check who the user is they complain about specifically. It so happens it is the user that in recent times was most vocal in complaining on meta about poor treatment of (new) users. This goes to show that in practice things are quite a bit more complicated. Finally, one should not forget that not every complaint is automatically reasonable. I invested some time to look through the posts of OP to see how they were treated. Did you? If yes, could you point to specific problems?

Comment: So, @wolfies  If I were to post on meta with a complaint about users like you who see things from a very immature perspecive, and the many, many users who participate here because users like you do their homework for them,  and demonstrate just upset I am by my treatment from users like you, and in addition, indeed,  I am so upset that I may quit the site....  Does that, therefore, motivate you to speak on my behalf, and acting like you know what I need?  Perhaps  "I'm so unhappy with my treatment that I wish to cancel my account".  Do we therefore conclude my complaint is valid?